# WebGate Configuration Problem

Tags: apache, oas

I have a instance of Oracle Access Manager set up on Server A and a copy of WebGate set up on Apache on Server B which should be working but isn't.  When I try to access http(s)://hostname:port/access/oblix/apps/ webgate/bin/webgate.cgi?progid=1 as specified in the [directions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28196_01/idmanage.1014/b25353/webgate.htm) after everything is set up, I get a web page that says:

> No Response from Application Web Server
>
> There was no response from the application web server for the page you requested. 
>   Please notify the site's webmaster and try your request again later.

I get the same error message when accessing other pages which are set up to be protected by WebGate with LocationMatch in Apache's httpd.conf.

Also, I'm not getting any output in webgate/access/oblix/logs/oblog.log even though webgate/access/oblix/conf/oblog_config_wg.xml has the log level set to LOGLEVEL_TRACE.

Does anyone have thoughts on what config files to check that could be causing this problem?

Edit 1: I've found that when I access a page protected by WebGate, the Apache error_log has this:

> [Thu Oct  8 09:44:23 2009] [notice] child pid 4970 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Edit 2: Also, for some reason, pages which are to be protected by WebGate don't trigger an update to Apache's access_log, even though they do return that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Webgate fixed the problem.  Not sure what screwed it up.

Answer (score 3):

Ah the joy of the webgate install. Here are the usual questions I ask myself:

Does the apache user also own the directory where webgate is installed? 
Are you running this on an OS and Apache version verified by Oracle? 
Is your httpd.conf correctly setup with the WebGate configs? 
Did you put
LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.4.19
export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL
in your init.d/httpd file?
Are you clocks in sync between the Access server and the apache host?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I never figured out what got messed up in the configuration, but a reinstall did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

i got

> [2014-03-27T04:41:51.2101+05:30] [OHS] [NOTIFICATION:16] [OHS-9999] [core.c]  [pid: 14931] [tid: 139749613860672] [user: root] [VirtualHost: main]  child pid 14952 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

along with

> Directory does not exist for read/write [.../oracle/middleware/Oracle_WT1/log] []

in OHS_HOME/network/log/sqlnet.log

After changing file permission of OHS directory appropriately. This issue got resolved for me.